# Why will my Powershell profile only load for the 32bit version of powershell?

Tags: powershell

As per this document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx I've created a profile in:

`%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

When I run the 64 bit version of PowerShell the profile doesn't load.  However when I run the x86 version the profile loads correctly.

How can I get my profile to load correctly in the 64bit version.

Comment: What did you put in the profile?

Comment: For the time being it is just a test. So function test() { Write-Host "TEST" }.  I've tried this on my machine, a colleagues and a server and I'm getting the same behaviour in all instances.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was a strange one in that after initially creating the profile in powershell I used  notepad++ to edit the file.

It looks like there's a bug in notepad++ where by it looks as though you're editing and saving the system32 version but you're actually editing the version is systemWOW64 (also documented by someone else here http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331754/topic/5004979)

If I edit and save the profile in notepad the script runs as expected.